# java.sql.SQLException: Could not set parameter at position 1 (values was 1) using jdbc.queryForObject

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, mariadb

Can not determine where the main cause of this exception. I did everything according to Spring in Action book. What is wrong with these lines of code?

```
private static final String PREFIX_SELECT_SQL = "SELECT ID, " +
        "CATEGORY_ID, " +
        "STATE_ID, " +
        "TASK_DESCRIPTION, " +
        "CREATION_TASK_DATE, " +
        "START_TASK_DATE, " +
        "END_TASK_DATE, " +
        "USER_ID FROM tasks ";

public Task findOneTask(int taskId) {
    Task task = jdbc.queryForObject(PREFIX_SELECT_SQL
            + "WHERE ID = " + taskId + ";", this::mapRowToTaskTable, taskId);
    return task;
}

private Task mapRowToTaskTable(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    Task task = new Task();

    task.setTaskId(resultSet.getInt("ID"));
    task.setUserId(resultSet.getInt("USER_ID"));
    task.setDescription(resultSet.getString("TASK_DESCRIPTION"));
    task.setCategoryId(resultSet.getInt("CATEGORY_ID"));
    task.setStateId(resultSet.getInt("STATE_ID"));
    task.setStartDate(resultSet.getTimestamp("START_TASK_DATE").toLocalDateTime());
    if (resultSet.getTimestamp("END_TASK_DATE") != null) {
        task.setEndDate(resultSet.getTimestamp("END_TASK_DATE").toLocalDateTime());
    } else {
        task.setEndDate(null);
    }
    task.setCreateDate(resultSet.getTimestamp("CREATION_TASK_DATE").toLocalDateTime());

    return task;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are already passing to jdbc.queryForObject query with concrete value, but not a parameter.

```
Select ...
from ...
where id = 123
```

Change findOneTask to:

```
public Task findOneTask(int taskId) {
  Task task = jdbc.queryForObject(PREFIX_SELECT_SQL
            + "WHERE ID = ?;", this::mapRowToTaskTable, taskId);
  return task;
}
```